# PROBLEM - "update - dependency problems - leaving unconfigured". Plus - boot 0 bytes

Tags: kernel, dpkg

I am a newbie at wits end. I have cleaned /boot using many different methods suggested on this site without success. /boot is still 0 bytes free with all old kernels removed. uname -r returns "3.16.0-48-generic". 49,50 and 51 are available in /boot. when I enter "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak" the following returns:

Package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-48-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-48-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
simon@Arthur:~$

[Result of "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAtZb.png)

Hope someone can help. I am on a steep learning curve. Thanks.

Comment: Smells like a full disk (or partition). Could you add the output of `df -h`?

Answer (score 0):

You have *not* removed older kernels.  You are still running an old one in fact.  You need to reboot so you are running the latest one, then you can remove an older one to free up some space with `sudo dpkg -r linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic`, then run `sudo apt-get install -f` to finish installing the half installed one, and finally `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean up all of the older ones.